# Python 2.7 TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7

not sure why my statement is giving me this error.  I am trying to open a file that the user enters the path.

```
import csv

f = open(raw_input('Enter file path: '),'r')[1:-1]
```

Comment: What do you expect the slice notation (`[1:-1]`) to do to a file object?

Comment: why do you want to remove the first and last letters of your input string? If would give an un usable path

Comment: Sorry this does seem to be the issue here, after removing the [1:-1] works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to open the file:

```
f = open('workfile', 'w')
```

If you want to read a part of the file you should let is read line by line after is opened. 
 
You don't need the [1:-1]

```
for line in f:
    print line
```